# How can I maintain C# primitive types above RedisValue when using StackExchange.Redis

Tags: c#, redis, stackexchange.redis

I started using the `StackExchange.Redis` client for storing key value pairs.

I have a nested dynamic object (`JObject`) and I flatten that object to a key-value structure that looks something like:

Lets assume the `JObject` looks like:

```
"Root":
{
   "Obj1":
    {
       "Prop":12,
       "Prop2": "StringValue"
    }
}
```

I flatten this object into a `Dictionary<string, object>` that generates key value pairs that look like:

```
key: "Root.Obj1.Prop" | value: 12
key: "Root.Obj1.Prop2" | value: "StringValue"
```

I'm using `object` and not `string` since my client knows how to handle various primitives (which aren't always `strings`).

The specific redis client excepts a `RedisValue` struct which has implicit castings for multiple types but not from object.

So I had to split my dictionary into different primitive enumerables in order to create RedisValues and to "maintain" their original types:

```
var strs = dic.Where(kvp => kvp.Value is string).Select(kvp => new HashEntry(kvp.Key, (string)kvp.Value));
var ints = dic.Where(kvp => kvp.Value is int).Select(kvp => new HashEntry(kvp.Key, (int)kvp.Value));
```

Now each value in the `ints` enumerable has a IsInteger property equal to true.

So after setting redis with those values, I'm now fetching the key-values from Redis and I have a bunch of RedisValues in my hand. I take one RedisValue which had a IsInteger property equal to true and see that it didn't really maintain that state.

My questions:

1. Is there any way I can maintain the real primitive types between sets and gets? I understand I have some boxing\unboxing issues by keeping them as 
   objects but I have lot's of benefit's in this specific app. Using a RedisValue struct isn't something that I'd like to do across my application. I'd like to keep that in a small specific layer that communicates with Redis.
2. If theres no way to do (1) then is there any good reason why the RedisValue doesn't keep the IsInteger property between sets and gets? When I set the RedisValue I have the IsInteger property set to true and when I fetch it, it's false.

Thank you.

Comment: How are you querying the data in Redis? Any need to break it down at all? If not, you could just store the JObject as a string with full type information for each property thus permitting correct deserialization.

Comment: I don't want to hold the complete json as a value since my data structure is by design a "flattened object". Redis fits like a glove to my "key-data" approach. Since I don't have any real structure behind my object, I want to maintain the original types. If I have an Age entry that I update with an int (as a RedisValue) I'd like to fetch that data as an int as well and not as a string.

Answer (score 3):

You could write an additional key per property with type information, e.g.

```
Root:Obj1:Prop=12
Root:Obj1:Prop:type=int

Root.Obj1.Prop2=StringValue
Root.Obj1.Prop2:type=string
```

and always retrieve the type key first so that you know how to convert the value key.

But I wouldn't recommend it.  Instead, I'd recommend one of two standard approaches, depending on how you intend to query the data via Redis.

1. Map strongly typed objects to Redis keys

   - Assumes that efficient querying via Redis operations is a priority
   - Allows you to localise your Redis specific code in a mapping class
2. Store a persisted object

   - Basically a BLOB of data.  Could be a complete JSON object (perhaps even including full type information for each property - there's an option to enable that with Json.Net) or an array of bytes using protobuf
   - Assumes you're using Redis just for storage; which is OK

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I know I can write and additional property for type info and I don't want to get there.

I can't map a strong type since my json object is complete dynamic (A third party service gives me small portions of data and I build this json on the fly).

I want to keep the data structure as it is now since I have other constraints that make it efficient and readable.

Thank you for the answer. +1 on the effort.

Comment: np, thanks for the feedback. Given your circumstances I suspect that the BLOB approach would work best for you. You mention that you really need to break down the object but without examples of the types of Redis queries you would make it's not possible to help.  It could be that my response isn't what you wanted to hear, but if you think it addresses the question then please mark it as accepted.  Thanks